# Apply Required Attribute if the value was binded by Model Binder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-annotations

I have to handle following validation scenario:

1. If Some condition is met then we're displaying textbox which should be mandatory
2. If not met value for the property should be optional

Model Looking kind of this:

```
public class Setting
{
    [Required]
    public string Domain { get; set; }
}
```

Is that possible to differentiate somehow when field value was omitted or it didn't bind? Cause as I know if the value was omitted or not bound the value of it would be a default(string). In this case, I'm not able to definite should Domain be provided or not

Comment: I think if a field is optional, you should not attach the `[Required]` attribute on it. Then do the checking in your C# code or if you can, use JavaScript to finish it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have situations where it may or may not be required, you're best bet may be to have your `Setting` class inherit from `IValidatableObject` and implement your own `Validate()` method. Do whatever checksyou need to to see if it's required or not and do a `yield return new ValidationResult("Description", new[] { nameof(Domain ) })` to explain why it's not valid.

If you can't make that determination inside your `Settings` class, then you'll likely have to do it in your controller action, and use something like `ModelState.AddModelError("Description", nameof(model.Domain)));` followed by checking `ModelState.IsValid` to see if the action should kick out and return a redirect/view